What do we call the overall dimensionality of a graph in relation to a domain and co-domain
To my understanding, is it valid to say that the domain and co-domain are the dimensionalities of the input $n$ and output $m$ of a function respectively?
$$\large F\colon\ \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$$
For example, if we have a function $f(x,y) = z$, the dimensionality of $n$ is 2 dimensional, while the dimensionality of $m$ is 1 dimensional. Graphically, we see a volume / 3D shape [edit: when a height is integrated over a surface]. So I'm assuming that the dimension of the graph is the dimensions of the domain and co-domain added together. My question is what is this dimension of the integration technically called/referred to? Is it always the addition of the domain and co-domain?
Moreover are there any mistakes/misunderstandings in how I understand what the domain and co-domain are? I'm really new to the terminologies of mathematics. Thank you!

Graphically that is not a volume but a surface.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The domain and codomain of a function are not "dimensionalities", they are sets. The domain is the set from which the inputs come, and the codomain is the set where you find the outputs. Given $F:{\bf R}^n\to{\bf R}^m$, the domain of $F$ is ${\bf R}^n$, and the codomain of $F$ is ${\bf R}^m$. The dimension of the domain is $n$, and the dimension of the codomain is $m$. To "draw" the graph of such a function, you would need a piece of $m+n$-dimensional graph paper. I don't know what you mean by "the integration", nor by the dimension of the integration.

The dimension of the graph is referred to as "the dimension of the graph". It is never the addition of the domain and the codomain; it is the sum of the dimension of the domain and the dimension of the codomain.

@Gerry Myerson thank you that clears it up. I suppose what I meant by dimension of the integration is the same as to "draw" the graph because the dimension of the shape created when integrating the co-domain over the domain is the same as the dimension of the graph. thanks for explaining these terminologies for me.
